# RESTful API not working using Grails RestfulController

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am working on creating a sample application, with extending **RestfulController**.

I am connecting to MySQL database, and here are my code snippets

**City.groovy**

```
package cityapic

class City {

    static constraints = {
        name blank:false
        pincode blank:false
    }

    def String name
    def String pincode
}
```

**CityController.groovy**

```
package cityapic

import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.rest.RestfulController

class CityController extends RestfulController {

    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    def index() {
    }
}
```

**UrlMappings.groovy**

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{ constraints { // apply constraints here
        } }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')

    "/cityAPI/city/"(resource: "city")
    }
}
```

It doesn't perform a POST (save) to database when I use this CURL expression:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 6d436808-017f-7b31-5577-65062417e7ad" -d '{
"name" : "Berhampur",
"pincode": "760001"
}' http://localhost:8080/cityAPIC/city
```

I know that the CURL expression is correct. There's some problem in the "save" part of the code.

Comment: Is your app running on ROOT context path?

Comment: I am sorry..very new to GRAILs and GROOVY. http://localhost:8080/cityAPIC/city is the URL to access via POSTMAN API client. What do you mean by ROOT context path please?

Comment: I guess you don't need cityAPIC in your URLMapping

Comment: what is the name of your grails app?

Comment: cityAPIC is the name

Comment: OK then try "/city/"(resource: "city") in your URLMappings

Comment: usually the grails app name is prefix of all URLMappings

Comment: If I run the CURL after your change, it gives me this error "HTTP Status 404 - "/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/city/index.gsp" not found."

Answer (score 1):

Change your URLMapping to:

`"/city"(resource: "city")`

or add an annotation on your domain class:

```
    import grails.rest.*

    @Resource(uri='/city', formats=["json", "xml"])
    class City {

        static constraints = {
            name blank:false
            pincode blank:false
        }

         def String name
         def String pincode
   }
```

The resource will be:
http://localhost:8080/cityAPIC/city

If you need to check all resources you can do:

`grails url-mappings-report`

This command will display  all available resources.

You can found more info on the grails doc:
[grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#REST](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#REST)

Comment: then my controller doesn't need to extend RestfulController?

Comment: @Swat there are mutiple ways to do REST. First is by exposing your domains as rest resources(this is simple and does not include customized logic). Second is by extending the RestfulController (in this you can override the CRUD methods and customize your logic in them). Third is Implementing REST Controllers Step by Step(in this you have control over every aspect of implementing REST right from what should be the api url end point->which controller's action->if any service function call->throw exceptions if any->fetch data->render response in format you desire). Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks swapnil! I was wondering if there are certain samples that I can follow for these types.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the transactional read only to false on the CityController.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
class CityController extends RestfulController {
```

Because Class [grails.rest.RestfulController](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/RestfulController.groovy) is readOnly by default